# Cross querys with CTE into single query (MSSQL)

Tags: sql-server

Good afternoon,

I've 2 tables into my SQL DB, in the first I've the asignation for days to a person, and other the registry per day of this person, I will like see if this person have or not registry for each day into the range of specification.

I've encountered a query that uses CTE for return the range in days independent, and other query in that I've the registry group by person and day, but I can't cross these queries.

Bottom there is a picture with queries and results of each.

Thanks.

[My SQL querys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CgIB.png)

Comment: It is rude to post only image without actual query/schema/sample data. Retyping is boring.

Comment: This is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: If you can, please also try to get a native English speaker help you to re-write the question.   I'm not sure I understand it at all.

Comment: Oh, excuse me, I am new on this site, and I am from Bogotá, my level English is bad, and Google Translate ocasionally don't translate Spanish to English good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use several CTEs in one statement, so you may put each query in separate CTE and join them later lake that:

[image]

```
SELECT
  p.cedula, p.starttime, 
  r.Descr, r.Candidad
FROM ctePeriod p
LEFT JOIN cteRegistry r on r.cedula = p.cedula AND r.Dia = p.StartTime
ORDER BY p.cedula, p.starttime
```

all above as a single query.

Another way is to put results of your Query1 and Query2 into temp tables and build your final query on those temp tables e.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ...
INTO #Period
FROM CTE
WHERE ...

SELECT ...
INTO #Registro
FROM Registro
GROUP BY ...

SELECT
  p.cedula, p.starttime, 
  r.Descr, r.Candidad
FROM #Period p
LEFT JOIN #Registro r on r.cedula = p.cedula AND r.Dia = p.StartTime
ORDER BY p.cedula, p.starttime
```

Comment: Oh thanks, this night try this and edit the post for more details, and comment if this answer run.

Comment: Thank you, the second part was very functional, never have been put queries into tempTables. Tank You